# Alternative way to get a reference to the underlying Ext.Window element of Ext.MessageBox in ExtJS4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, upgrade

In ExtJS 3 I am using method `getDialog()` to get reference of underlying `Ext.Window` element of Ext.MessageBox

In ExtJS 4 there is no such method which can get me this reference.

Part of code, I am using now:

```
var msgBox = Ext.MessageBox.getDialog()
```

Is there any other way to get this reference?

Answer (score 2):

When you call static method from `Ext.MessageBox` it returns reference to the dialog. So you can use it like any other window. For example:

```
var w = Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Confirm', 'Are you sure you want to do that?', showResult);
w.close();
```

(Update) I've just discovered that `Ext.MessageBox` is reference to the window itself. So you can write:

```
Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Confirm', 'Are you sure you want to do that?', showResult);
Ext.MessageBox.close();
```